# CS50 Pset9 Finance TraceBack, FileNotFoundError, AttributeError

Tags: python, cs50

Pset9 Finance, please help! When I put my API_Key and run flask, I get these errors that I haven't seen before and don't know how to fix:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachelib/file.py", line 219, in delete
os.remove(self._get_filename(key))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmplxzjvek9/f65da5cfc2b86410e5c673fb6ba2227e'

I have been stuck for the past 2 hours trying to fix this. I tried to ignore them and start the problem set by doing the register part and when I test it I get more issues (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get') as you can see. Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIgrg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ijc6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyTXd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, `request.method` is a string, so you can't call the `.get()` method on it. That method is not defined for strings.

I am not familiar with CS50's problem sets. That being said, it appears that you're trying to access parameters associated with the request on lines 124-126, which is the location of your issue.

For query parameters, use `request.args.get('...')`.

For body parameters, use `request.form.get('...')`.

Comment: Thanks! I realized now that I was using request.method.get instead of using request.form.get.